# Having had fallen asleep

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, tenses, past-tense

When I am referring to something that has occurred yesterday evening as I was falling asleep (continuous action, it took place **while** I was falling asleep), but it is no longer occurring and I am no longer falling asleep nor asleep, is it alright to use "having had fallen asleep"? It seemed correct when I used it, but I am having doubts now since it sounds so shabby.
Thanks!

to specify the sentence: *"It's still healthier than my having had fallen asleep to this. [a link to an online debate]"*

P.S.: I did try to look it up, but I am still uncertain.

Comment: The inclusion of _had_ makes the extract ungrammatical. You should omit it. You could also omit the _my_ if it is clear that you are referring to yourself. And just a tip for future questions: It is always a good idea to include at least a full sentence when asking questions about grammaticality.

Comment: Thanks! The sentence is included in italics. :)

Comment: That's not a sentence!

Comment: Edited. The sentence is taken from an IM.

Comment: Got it! If you want to look up this construction, do a search on "_perfect gerund_".

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comment. I seem to be getting confused when there are too many events/temporal factors to consider. I will look it up.